# Why does this simple mysql_query/SELECT/echo get "Array" as output?

Tags: php, mysql

I have written the code below, which should check the session variable against the database and give me the username which = user id which is in the session.

If I `echo $session_name;` I get a user id e.g. 30
If I `echo $row2;` I get Array

What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
        connect();
        $session_name = $_SESSION[id];
        $sql2 = "SELECT username FROM members WHERE member_id = '$session_name'";
            $result2=mysql_query($sql2);
            $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
        echo $row2;
        ?>
```

Comment: Please also add a [mysql] tag to your question. I was going to do that, but somehow the retag link is missing.

Comment: And while you're at it, read: [Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

try

```
echo $row2[0];
```

or even

```
print_r($row2);
```

to see what you are getting from db.

Answer (score 1):

Try echoing `$row2[0]`.  `mysql_fetch_array` returns one result row as an indexed array, which in this case has only one element/column.  Also don't forget to test if `$row2 === FALSE`, which indicates that there were no results for the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
        connect();
        $session_name = $_SESSION[id];
        $sql2 = "SELECT username FROM members WHERE member_id = '$session_name' LIMIT 1";
            $result2=mysql_query($sql2);
            while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
               echo $row2['username'];
?>
```

Comment: perfect exactly what i wanted. Works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

The result of a fetch is always an array. In this case it's a one-dimensional array. Use `$row2[0]` (assuming your fetchmode is an array).

If your fetchmode is associative or object, it'd be `$row2['username']`.

Check here for more good info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Answer (score 0):

$row2 is in fact an array that represents the entire row returned. Try $row2[0], I think that will give you what you expected (the single field in the returned row).

Answer (score 0):

That's because `$row2` **is** an array. You used `mysql_fetch_array` to obtain it, and it returns an array, as the name of the function implies.

The array returned by `mysql_fetch_array` uses the column names from your SQL query as the keys. Thus

```
echo $row2['username'];
```

will return the data you expect.

As a sidenote: `SELECT` is technically a SQL *clause*, not a PHP function.